# WSServletContextLi stener contextDestroyed while deploying war using cobertura 

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, cobertura

Hi I am new to cobertura , i created a war using cobertura while deploying this war in tomcat i am getting below error message

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.4 (FCS b09) for context '/victor'
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/victor] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:07 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextLi
stener contextDestroyed enter code here`
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearRefere
ncesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/victor] appears to have started a thread named [Th
read-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThread
LocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/victor] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [nu
ll] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@14ec141]) and a value of type [java.util.H
ashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it whe
n the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:17 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9009
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:17 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Apr 02, 2012 1:22:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 276800 ms
```

Comment: what is the java version u r using ??? if Ur java version is 1.7 then revert back to 1.6 and try

Comment: if Ur application supports 1.5 u can try

Comment: @ vinad then you need to comment like once check your java version or your java version(used for cobertura instumentation) must be matched with your application using java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just i changed my java version to 1.6 i used to compile sources with 1.7 for Cobertura instrumentation.